# Angular 5 - Read form data posted from another site

Tags: angular, identityserver4

Third party site does authentication and redirects users to my Angular 5 site. While redirecting users, it posts form data (id tokens) to my site written in Angular 5 where I have to read the posted form data and proceed.

Can you please shed some light where I can collect this posted form data in Angular 5?

Note: Third party site uses Identity Server 4 for authentication with One-Time-Password.

Thanks and appreciate your help!

Comment: can you elaborate the current scenario please??

Comment: I just need to receive form data posted to my Angular 5 site from another site. We used to collect it like HttpContext.Request.Form["PostedData"] in traditional .NET MVC applications.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this:

[example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ggnsje)

```
private FormData:any;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.getPostedData();
  }

  getPostedData() {
    this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp)
    this.FormData = resp.get('form');
    console.log(this.FormData);
    })
  }
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Actually, I am getting 'Can't post' error while form-posting to Angular site from an external site. Do you have any thoughts?